# Measuring/Monitoring response time of each execution of a sql

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-performance, query-performance

In Oracle 11g, I want to monitor the response time of a specific sql (I know the sql_id of the sql). Meaning, I want to know the response time of the sql every time it is executed. I would "turn it on" for some time and then would like to see a data something like:

`For sql_id 'abcdefg', following were the execution time (in ms)
10
12
10
13
10
10
10
240
230
10
9
12
…
…`

We can ignore the exact format I would like to see the output, but is there any way for me to monitor such that I can get the response time for every execution for my sql?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should trace your sql (assume `sql_id`:`6b0z40gs9m759`):

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET sql_trace=TRUE;

SQL> ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS 'trace[rdbms.SQL_Optimizer.*][sql:6b0z40gs9m759]';
[ SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET EVENTS 'sql_trace [sql:&&sql_id] bind=true, wait=true'; ] -- or use this as alternative.

SQL> ALTER SESSION SET TRACEFILE_IDENTIFIER = "TrcSqlParag"; -- adds this text to your trace file and makes it more recognizable by you.

SQL> SHOW PARAMETER user_dump_dest -- trace files are produced in this directory

-- For 11g DB, you may easily query v$diag_info view to see your file destination :
SQL> SELECT value FROM   v$diag_info WHERE  name = 'Default Trace File';

-- You can identify the trace file for a specific session using the V$SESSION and V$PROCESS views :
SQL> SELECT p.tracefile FROM v$session s JOIN v$process p ON s.paddr = p.addr WHERE  s.sid = &ses_id;

-- You may finish tracing whenever you want :
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET sql_trace=FALSE;
```

Let's have such a dump file :

```
/u01/app/oracle/admin/MYDB11G/udump/mydb11g_ora_TrcSqlParag.trc
```

The trace file is not easy to read, we need `tkprof utility` to read it from OS :

```
$ cd /u01/app/oracle/admin/MYDB11G/udump/
$ tkprof mydb11g_ora_TrcSqlParag.trc TrcSqlParag_Translated1.txt explain=<username>/<pwd>@mydb11g table=sys.plan_table sys=no waits=yes
```

Comment: Hi Barbaros, though the stackoverflow guidelines say don't add a comment to say "thanks", I am just saying that for now. Because I did try out what you said and it worked for my specific session, but I want to do this for the entire app (I am guessing "alter system" instead of "alter session" would do) and then see if I am able to collate the data and finally get the query response time that I am looking for. Thanks for such nicely written detailed steps (even "personalized" steps too!). I will update the thread in a couple of days.

Comment: Hi Barbaros, I tried the above with "alter system" and things worked - though it was a bit painful to identify my trace files as I couldn't name them. I have a java code takes system time just before stmt.executeQuery, just after it and then once after looping through the entire resultset. Then it prints how long each step took. I am trying to map the numbers that I get from the trace to this and having some difficulty in correlating the numbers. I will try more and add to the thread if I find something interesting there.